# How can i take highest date in same person

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi I have two table like that:

- First:  Tcustcounselm
- Second: Tcustcounseldt

`Tcustcounseldt` include these columns : `Counsel_Seq, Proc_Note, Proc_Date`
`Tcustcounselm` include these columns : `Counsel_Seq, Cust_No, Proc_Date`

I have customers and I want to retrieve the customer proc_note (refund detail). Some customers have more than one refund detail, I only want the latest one.

This is my plsql code but when I run it it gives the same cust_no twice when I only want to see the latest one.

```
   Select 
       A.Cust_No,
       Max(To_Char(B.Proc_Date, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')) As Proc,
       B.Proc_Note,
       A.Counsel_Seq
   FROM Tcustcounselm A,
       Tcustcounseldt B
   WHERE 
       A.Counsel_Seq = B.Counsel_Seq
       --AND B.Do_Flag       ='40'
   AND A.Proc_Date BETWEEN TO_DATE('2013/07/08', 'YYYY/MM/DD') AND TO_DATE('2013/07/08', 'YYYY/MM/DD')+1
   GROUP BY 
       A.Cust_No,
       B.Proc_Note,
       A.Counsel_Seq
   ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

I thınk MAX is  problem  so  i tried different sample code but same problem

```
               SELECT  A.Cust_No,
               B.Proc_Note
               FROM Tcustcounselm A ,
          (SELECT Counsel_Seq,
              Proc_Note,
              Rank () Over (Partition By Counsel_Seq  Order By Proc_Date Desc) As              Priority
              From Tcustcounseldt
           ) B
          Where A.Counsel_Seq = B.Counsel_Seq
          --And B.Priority      = 1
          AND A.Proc_Date BETWEEN TO_DATE('2013/07/08', 'YYYY/MM/DD') AND   TO_DATE('2013/07/08', 'YYYY/MM/DD')+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This (or somehing similar) should work

```
   SELECT  A.Cust_No,
           To_Char(B.Proc_Date, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') As Proc,
           B.Proc_Note,
           A.Counsel_Seq
      FROM Tcustcounselm B 
INNER JOIN Tcustcounseldt A
        ON A.Counsel_Seq = B.Counsel_Seq
     WHERE (A.Cust_No,B.Proc_Date) IN ( SELECT A.Cust_No,
                                               max(B.Proc_Date) PD
                                          FROM Tcustcounselm B
                                    INNER JOIN Tcustcounseldt A
                                            ON A.Counsel_Seq = B.Counsel_Seq
                                      GROUP BY A.Cust_No)
```

I had time to play with sqlfiddle and I fixed the query, try to check it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/35bb1/2).

Comment: Hey thanx for answering but i have problem like that ORA_01861 literal doesnot match format string . I researcing but thx again

Comment: sorry, I forgot to remove the other side of the to_char :)

Comment: mucio it doesnt work  same problem in your source code .Same customer coming .I want to different customer and latest time refund detail .

Comment: check now, there is also the link to sqlfiddle

Comment: mucio i think you add different coloum and also when i change it again same . Tcustcounseldt :Counsel_Seq, Proc_Note,Proc_Date.Tcustcounselm:Counsel_Seq,Custno like that . I hope it help again to solve problem .